# Instance variable String in Outer Class being set to null before Inner Class can use it

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I'm working on a project to implement the game "Monopoly" in Java. I've currently setup a GUI on top of my client code to take text input to a chat box (or to send commands) to the server.

My Controller.java class is the code to start the GUI. When a user enters the IP and port of the game server and hits submit, the server listening to that Socket then instantiates a thread of the Controller.java inner class ClientServiceThread. This class is what should send messages between the GUI - Client - Server.

My problem is that in the outer class (Controller.java) I have an instance variable called "messageText". Later on when a user enters a message to the Chatbox, I assign that text to the "messageText" variable. However, when I attempt to grab that variable in the ClientServiceThread, it is always null. I believe this is because the server created both a new client and a new controller, which would mean the variable I'm trying to get hasn't actually been modified.

**Server Code Snippet**

```
public void run() {

    try {
        myServerSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Could not create server socket on port 8888. Quitting.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println("Server successfully started");

    while(ServerOn) {
        try {
            Socket clientSocket = myServerSocket.accept();
            Controller.ClientServiceThread cliThread = new Controller().new ClientServiceThread(clientSocket, clientidnum);
            cliThread.start();

            //adds clients to array in order they join
            connectedClients[clientidnum] = cliThread;

            //increments connected ID client var
            clientidnum++;
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Exception found on accept. Ignoring. Stack Trace :");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Controller.java Code Snippet**

```
public class Controller extends Application implements Initializable  {

    Socket myClientSocket;
    boolean m_bRunThread = true;
    String hostname;
    int hostportnumber;
    private ObservableList<String> chatMessages = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    String messageText = "";

    private void handleChatAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        if (event.getSource() == sendchatButton){
            String chat = chatInput.getText();
            if(chat != null && !chat.trim().isEmpty()) {
                chatMessages.add(chat);
                messageText = chat;
                chatmessagesList.setItems(chatMessages);
                chatmessagesList.scrollTo(chatMessages.size());
            }
            chatInput.clear();
        }
}
```

**Inner Class ClientServiceThread Snippet**

```
class ClientServiceThread extends Thread {
    Socket myClientSocket;
    boolean m_bRunThread = true;
    String hostname;
    int hostportnumber;
    int id;

    public ClientServiceThread() {
        super();
    }

    ClientServiceThread(Socket s, int clientid) {
        myClientSocket = s;
        id = clientid;
    }

    public String getTextField(){
        if(Controller.this.messageText != "") {
            return Controller.this.messageText;
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        BufferedReader in = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        System.out.println("Accepted Client Address - " + myClientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());

        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myClientSocket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(myClientSocket.getOutputStream()));

            while(m_bRunThread) {
                String clientCommand = getTextField();
                System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand);
```

I apologize for the huge walls of code. I've taken out hundreds of lines of code just to reduce the amount you need to sift through. This bug is really hindering me and I can't progress to develop the actual game unless the client can communicate with the server.

Here are links to a gist of the full files of code if you wish to have a look at them. Thanks!

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0961189791b8127598b3b3d7ca527987

Comment: you mentioned that "when I attempt to grab that variable in the ClientServiceThread, it is always null", i can't seem to see where you're attempting that within the ClientServiceThread class

Comment: There are no references to `messageText` anywhere except in `Controller.java`.  The question is not currently answerable.

Comment: Apologies, in my post I forgot to add this code. This function is in the inner class ClientServiceThread...
    `public String getTextField(){
        if(Controller.this.messageText != "") {
            return Controller.this.messageText;
        }
       else {
            return Controller.this.messageText;
       }
    }`

Comment: This code is run in the second last line of the ClientServiceThread snippet (String clientCommand = getTextField();)

Comment: I've also updated the code snippet's in my main question above with the getTextField() function @OusmaneDiaw

Comment: @Woooooooooooooow i will have a look.

Comment: @Woooooooooooooow shouldn't "getTextField" getter method be inside the Controller class since it's the Controllers property.

Comment: Ideally, yes. But the problem is that I can't understand a way to have the ClientServiceThread receive the input of the GUI chatbox without that method. Also, the getTextField() should return the message contained in Controller.this.messageText however it always appears to be null, even when I have typed something.